# BeautifulSoup and Selenium cannot fetch <p> content under nested <div>

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape reviews from a webpage. The attached image shows that the reviews are in `<p>` tag under a div class named "more reviewdata". [image: After clicking Inspect]I have used BeautifulSoup first and then Selenium for extracting the "more reviewdata" portion but failed, though other `<p>` and `<div>` tags are extracting nicely. One of the several tutorial websites I visited, hinted that a dynamic page will not show all sources by clicking on Inspect. But here the review content is showing after clicking Inspect, which means this page is not dynamic. Is anybody there to suggest. Thanks in advance. For BeautifulSoup, my code is like this:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.mouthshut.com/hindi-movies/Tanhaji-reviews-925997893'
response = requests.get(url)
page_contents = response.text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(page_contents, 'html.parser')
```

For Selenium and Chrome Driver I wrote:

```
from selenium import webdriver    
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=options)
import time    
driver.get("https://www.mouthshut.com/hindi-movies/Tanhaji-reviews-925997893")
more_review_data_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("more reviewdata")
page_contents = driver.page_source
```

Comment: try class name more.reviewdata (note the dot in between)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of multiple class names you should use css selector or XPath.
So instead of

```
more_review_data_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("more reviewdata")
```

Try this:

```
more_review_data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".more.reviewdata p")
```

or this

```
more_review_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='more reviewdata']//p")
```

Also you should add some wait to make the page loaded before accessing the elements. So it will be something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.more.reviewdata p")))
time.sleep(0.5)
more_review_data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".more.reviewdata p")
```

or

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='more reviewdata']//p")))
time.sleep(0.5)
more_review_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='more reviewdata']//p")
```

To simply print the texts inside the element you can iterate on the elements list and print each element text like this:

```
for element in more_review_data:
    print(element.text)
```

or

```
for element in more_review_data:
    print(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Comment: I tried your code and it is returning this: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4ed11678498c1cf0d68fa180b934fe85", element="1732f835-78ed-47da-aaa7-1090b939b702")>`. What should I do next?

Comment: What did you try to do? It gives you a web element itself, not the text inside it. Do you want to extract the text or something more?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract text inside it. I went through the find_element_ function list but cannot figure out how to proceed.

Comment: I have added code to print texts. Pay attention, I added `p` parent inside the locator to get the `p` element itself, not the parent `div`. Both should work correct, however it's better to do thing exactly.

Comment: It's showing error dear `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable` in the line `for element in more_review_data:`

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope now it will work correctly

Comment: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no attribute 'visibility_of_elements_located'

Comment: I know, already removed that, see the updated code

Comment: Wow! It's perfectly working. Thank you very much for being with my problem for so long.

Answer (score 2):

As you load the site contents for reviews are dynamic loaded so if you go to the `Developer mode` to `Network tab` and find data related to reviews link will appear which contents all reviews related to site!.

Code:

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://www.mouthshut.com/Review/rar_reviews.aspx?cname=Tanhaji&cid=925997893&movie=1")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
```

here I have used css class selector which returns list of data

```
main_data=soup.select("div.more.reviewdata")
for i in main_data:
    print(i.find("p").get_text())
```

Here's the output of above script:

```
   The movie is on real fact there was war for Kondhana ghad Tanhaji Malusare had attack on mughul on  4th - Feb 1670 and the brave fighter Tanhaji's one hand was cutted by Udaybhan but they still fighting and The Maratha's win the war I love the film and the unity of sawarj also great described in the film 
. ....
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: I'll ask the editor of this answer to restore the image that was quiet relevant and helpful for us to get the idea better.

Comment: Okay let me add it sorry i approved it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='class name']")
```

in your case

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='more reviewdata']")
```

Comment: this does not look like python

Comment: yeah , fixed it